# HTTP "get-request" and receiving audio/mpeg content type

Tags: java, http, audio, mpeg

I am going to write a Java program that does a HTML "get"-request. The response is a MP3 file.

The question is: Which Java class/methods can be used for doing this and how can the MP3 file received and stored in a folder ?

(Background: Desktop is connected to teh Internet, Java program is running on Desktop and send a request to an URL that responses via a content-type audio/mpeg. But how can I receive this mp3 file  ?)

Thanks and best regards 
Harald

Answer (score 0):

The simplest approach is to use a java.net.URL and its openStream method to read the data bytes and write it to a file using a java.io.FileOutputStream.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer. If I write the downloaded file by using java.io.FileOutputStream, will I get the mp3 format ? Please be aware that I want to play this file afterwards directly with a mp3 player (on raspberry pi). That means I will write it in a folder and raspberry pi mp3 player should play it.

Comment: I don't know much about Rasperry Pi, but normally, when you name your file with a .mp3 extension the player should recognize and play it.